# Is it possible to delete/reset a single Streetpass Plaza game's progress without nuking the others'?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza

In Streetpass Mansion / Monster Manor, I have made some dumb decisions that have made it basically impossible to progress. On the other hand, I am enjoying several of the others and wouldn't want to lose my progress in those games. Is there a way to delete the one without also removing the others?

Comment: According to Gamefaqs, in settings you should have "delete [insert game name] progress" or something to that affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Gamefaqs, in settings you should have

```
Delete [insert game name] progress
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: The general settings of the 3ds, or the settings of the game itself?

Comment: @Mathias711 It should be in StreetPass Plaza settings

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By going into the StreetPass settings > Other Options > Delete [game] Progress this will delete the progress of selected game (without affecting the progress of the other games)

Confirmed through personal experience by deleting the progress of a game (and even deleting the game itself) and other StreetPass games' progress remains unaffected.